# Alternative to LIKE clause in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have got a filed in my database table which stores categories. I am storing the categories in the following format:

`1,12,15`

Now when I try to search for a product from category 1,
I use `LIKE` clause in my query such as

`where (prod_catg LIKE %1,% or prod_catg LIKE %1% or prod_catg LIKE %,1% )`

This returns me the products from all the three categories 1,12 and 15. Instead I just want the products from category 1.

I have also tried `IN` clause but no results found.

Can anyone please suggest me some other alternative.

Comment: you should normalize your scema by adding a table `category` and then reference to it in the main table

Answer (score 8):

```
prod_catg LIKE '1,%' --matches when 1 is the first category
OR prod_catg LIKE '%,1,%' --matches when 1 is somewhere in the middle
OR prod_catg LIKE '%,1' --matches 1 when is the last category
```

anyway you had better to refactor your schema by adding a category table and the reference to it on the product (main) table

**EDIT**

another way to face this problem is using [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) which will lead to a shorter `WHERE` clause (here is what i've used to test):

```
DECLARE @regexp VARCHAR(100);
SET @regexp = '^1,.*|.*,1$|.*,1,.*';

SELECT
    '1,11,15,51,22,31' REGEXP @regexp AS test1,
    '51,11,15,1,22,31' REGEXP @regexp AS test2,
    '11,15,51,22,31,1' REGEXP @regexp AS test3,
    '7,11,15,51,22,31' REGEXP @regexp AS test4,
    '51,11,15,7,22,31' REGEXP @regexp AS test5,
    '11,15,51,22,31,7' REGEXP @regexp AS test6;
```

this will match your `prod_catg` against the Regular Expression `'^1,.*|.*,1$|.*,1,.*'` returnig `1 (TRUE)` if it matches, `0 (FALSE)` otherwise.

Then your WHERE clause will look like:

```
WHERE prod_catg REGEXP '^1,.*|.*,1$|.*,1,.*'
```

explanation of regexp:

```
^1,.* --matches 1 at the beginning of a string followed by a `,` and any other char
.*,1$ --matches 1 at the end of a string preceded by a `,` and any other char
.*,1,.* --matches 1 between two `,` which are sourrounded by any other chars
| --is the OR operator
```

i'm sure this regexp could be much more compact but i'm not that good with regular expressions

obviuosly you can change the category you're looking for in the regular expression (try to replace `1` with `7` on the example above)

Answer (score 6):

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1', prod_catg)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a **many to many** relation between products and categories. You should create a new table to store the coresponding categories(cat_ids) for each product. You shouldn't have a column containing multiple category ids. This way your select would be much easier and a lot faster.